# undefined is not a function em Node.js usando Mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, query, mongodb

Eu sei que esse erro pode ter varias causas, mas nao conseguir saber ate agora a minha. Eu tenho uma função para salvar um Documento no meu MongoDB e eu estou usando callback para isso. O código e executado ate salvar o novo documento, depois disso eu tenho um erro. O código e o seguinte:

```
function saveUser(userName, socialMediaType, socialMediaID, setDocNumber, callback){
    var user;

    if(socialMediaType == "fbUID"){
         user = new users({
            userName: userName, 
            userEmail: 'userEmail',
            teams:[],
            fbUID : socialMediaID
         });
        }else 
          if(socialMediaType =="google"){
      //do the same
    }

   var query = {}
    query["'"+ socialMediaType +"'" ] = socialMediaID

     users.findOne(query, function(err, userFound){

       if (err) { // err in query
        log.d("Error in query FoundUser", err)
        log.d("User Found", userFound)
    }else 

    if(userFound == undefined){ //if user does not exist

          user.save(function(err, user){
        if(err) return console.error(err);
        log.d("user saved", user);
        currentSession =  sessionOBJ.login(user._id, socialMediaID);  
        callback(currentSession,"created")

     });

      }else{


        currentSession =  sessionOBJ.login(userFound._id, socialMediaID);  
        callback(currentSession,"logged")

      }


        });

}
```

Eu chamo a função através da função abaixo:

```
f(fbUID !== undefined){

    userModelOBJ.saveUser(userName,"fbUID", fbUID, function(currentSession, status) {

        res.send({"status":status,  
            "sessionID": currentSession.sessionID,
            "expires" : currentSession.date});
    });
```

Mas eu continuo com o seguinte error:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O erro é na seguinte linha :

```
callback(currentSession,"created")
```

Alguém pode me ajudar com isso?

Já fiz muitas pesquisas mas não consigo achar uma resposta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sua função `saveUser` espera 5 parâmetros. Ao chamá-la, você só passou 4. O 5º - `callback` - é portanto `undefined`, de modo que quando você tenta chamá-lo como função ele lança o erro "undefined não é uma função".

Pelo visto, o parâmetro faltante é `setDocNumber`, passe-o para a função e o problema deve se resolver. Ou então remova-o, se ele não for relevante (noto que ele não é usado em parte alguma no seu código).

Comment: É verdade. Obrigada pela resposta. :)

Answer (score 3):

Acredito que o seu problema seja na quantidade de parametros passados na chamada da função, voce passou quatro parametros em sua chamada em quanto na função mesmo voce usou 5 parametros.

```
f(fbUID !== undefined){

-->     userModelOBJ.saveUser(userName,"fbUID", fbUID, function(currentSession, status) {

            res.send({"status":status,  
                "sessionID": currentSession.sessionID,
                "expires" : currentSession.date});
        });
}
```

Comment: Nossa, que vacilo. Muito obrigada por sua resposta. Eu so escolhi a segunda porque achei mais completa.:)

Comment: vacilo comum mesmo, normalmente focamos na função, onde erramos e nem percebemos a chamada dela.